# OsTicket Plugin Issue

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, osticket

The issue I'm facing occurs when trying to enable the AD plugin on OsTicket's Admin Panel. I've downloaded the correct file from the osticket website, [Plugins Link](https://osticket.com/download/#ostPlugin). Once the file has been downloaded, I added the auth-ldap.phar file to the **/include/plugins** folder, just like OsTicket mentioned on their support page. After the file was added, I reset xampp services and logged into the Admin panel so I can enable the plugin, but when I try to add the plugin it doesn't seem like OsTicket is seeing the file, check out the screenshots (sorry I have low rep :/, so cannot embed).

[OsTicket not seeing the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SulZa.jpg)

[The file is in the plugins folder!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTJUE.jpg)

I've checked php.ini file, and not sure what I need to look for in order to enable this plugin feature. I've tried adding the full path to the file in the php.ini folder and removed the "**;**" for "**extension=ldap**".

[Not sure if I did this right but I added a path to the phar file, which still does not seem to be working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrzvl.jpg)

No clue on what else is missing, are there other extensions or files I must edit in order for Osticket to read the phar files? If it helps, I m running this on Apache, which is tied to XAMPP Control Panel.

Some info:
Running this on a windows server 2019 with desktop interface
Using Apache with mysql, which are tied to Xampp Control Panel
Using PHP

Thanks for checking into this!

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message and your debugging attempts

Comment: Also, is this in any way related to programming?

Comment: Hi Nico, I believe there might be some programming involved, but not sure if I just need to edit the configurations of a php file or something else. There really is no error, the screenshot "OsTicket not seeing the plugin", is the only message I seen when I try to add the AD file. From some of the videos I've seen, users would normally add the file to the /include/plugins folder like I did, and clicked on Add Plugin, once they did that, they had the option to add that feature on OsTicket.